# Calling function with pointer reference without assigning address

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm working with a well-established PLC (programmable logic controller) program that implements libraries written in C.

I'm trying to understand how pointers work in this setup, because it doesn't make sense to me.

lib.h

```
typedef struct {
/* Input Parameter */
short int   X;                      /*Setpoint*/
short int   Y;                      /*Actual*/
/* Output Parameter */
short int   Z;                      /*Setpoint-Actual*/
}difference_Typ;
```

lib.c

```
int tdelta(difference_Typ *d)
{
     d->Z = d->X-d->Y;

     return 0;
}
```

main.c

```
_GLOBAL     difference_Typ      Volts;

void main()
{
    Volts.X=5;
    Volts.Y=1;
    tdelta(Volts);
}
```

This is incredibly simplified, but functions are called by the name of the variable (not the address of the variable), and the variable is not defined as a reference. Then, in the library, it accesses the structure by using a pointer.

This works, but is it supposed to?

Comment: that should not compile. Passing a struct, expecting a pointer on struct. of course, if prototype isn't exported, that could compile to UB.

Comment: *This works* How do you know it "works"?

Comment: The library uses this method every time it calls a user-defined structure, and is being used on hundreds of PLCs right now. It must be specific to the controllers being used and the platform that compiles it (B&R)

Comment: What compiler is that? Also, are you 100% sure tricks like `typedef struct {...} difference_Typ[1];` weren't used?

Comment: You should post the actual code. The *"incredibly simplified"* code is not helping anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not supposed to work.

It may work on certain compilers - if they decide to implement passing a structure by actually passing a pointer. But it certainly isn't guaranteed that your compiler works this way.

Additionally, if you have a correct prototype for your function that is included in both files, then one or the other file won't compile (because then the compiler would know what the argument should be).

Comment: *It may work on certain compilers - if they decide to implement passing a structure by actually passing a pointer.*  Wouldn't that violate the pass-by-value semantics of **6.5.2.2 Function calls**, paragraph 2:  "... Each  argument  shall
have a type such that its **value may be assigned to an object**..." and paragraph 4:  "each parameter is **assigned the value of the
corresponding argument**."?  Per footnote 93:  "A function may change the values of its parameters, but **these changes cannot affect the values of the arguments**."

Comment: @AndrewHenle presumably the callee makes a copy, or perhaps it only makes a copy if it modifies the structure.